How to pass JSON data into mvvm model with multipart in Android kotlin?
My JSON data I will pass into an API:
{
    "restaurantId" : "073d9089-e318-4133-9364-671b4c47a874",
    "name" : "Sayaji",
    "address" : "Virani chock",
    "cityId" : "f94d6808-a8e9-45e9-a22d-6f41f6446580",
    "proviceId" : "2cdf1e1f-bc07-4873-893a-6357b09f92a5",
    "countryId" : "2d0450c7-59b8-422b-9aa5-1b3877c63c9c",
    "availabilities": [
        {
            "dayName": "Sunday",
            "isOpen": 1,
            "startTime": "09:00 AM",    
            "endTime": "09:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "dayName": "Monday",
            "isOpen": 2,
            "startTime": "09:00 AM",
            "endTime": "09:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "dayName": "Tuesday",
            "isOpen": 1,
            "startTime": "09:00 AM",
            "endTime": "09:00 PM"
        }
        ]  
}

My View Model:
 private var updateRestaurantProfile = MutableLiveData<GetRestaurantDetailModel>()
    fun getObserveUpdateRestaurantProfile() = updateRestaurantProfile
    fun updateRestaurantProfile(
        restaurantId:String,
        name: String,
        address: String,
        cityId: String,
        proviceId: String,
        countryId: String,
        availabilities: ArrayList<AvailabilitiesModel>
    ) {
        val builder = MultipartBody.Builder()
        builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM)

        if (name.isNotEmpty()) {
            builder.addFormDataPart("name", name)
        }

        if (address.isNotEmpty()) {
            builder.addFormDataPart("address", address)
        }

        builder.addFormDataPart("cityId", cityId)
        builder.addFormDataPart("proviceId", proviceId)
        builder.addFormDataPart("countryId", countryId)
        builder.addFormDataPart("restaurantId",restaurantId)

        if (availabilities.isNotEmpty()) {
            for (i in availabilities.indices) {
                builder.addFormDataPart("availabilities", availabilities[i].toString())
            }
        }

        val requestBody = builder.build()

        if (!this::repository.isInitialized) {
            repository = HomeRepository()
        }
        isLoading.value = true
        repository.updateRestaurantProfile(requestBody).observeForever {
            if (it.status == ResponseStatus.SUCCESS) {
                updateRestaurantProfile.value = it.data
            } else {
                errorListener.value = it.status
            }
            isLoading.value = false
        }
    }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

data class RestaurantUser(
    val restaurantId: String,
    val name: String,
    val address: String,
    val cityId: String,
    val provinceId: String,
    val countryId: String,
    val availabilities: List<RestaurantAvailability>
)

data class RestaurantAvailability(
    val dayName: String,
    val isOpen: Int,
    val startTime: String,
    val endTime: String
)

class RestaurantViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val repository = Repository()
    private val _updateStatus = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val updateStatus: LiveData<Boolean> = _updateStatus

    fun updateRestaurantProfile(restaurantUser: RestaurantUser) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val requestBody = multipartRequestBody(restaurantUser)
                val response = repository.updateRestaurantProfile(requestBody)
                _updateStatus.value = response.isSuccessful
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _updateStatus.value = false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun multipartRequestBody(restaurantUser: RestaurantUser): RequestBody {
        val builder = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        builder.addFormDataPart("restaurantId", restaurantUser.restaurantId)
        builder.addFormDataPart("name", restaurantUser.name)
        builder.addFormDataPart("address", restaurantUser.address)
        builder.addFormDataPart("cityId", restaurantUser.cityId)
        builder.addFormDataPart("proviceId", restaurantUser.provinceId)
        builder.addFormDataPart("countryId", restaurantUser.countryId)

        restaurantUser.availabilities.forEachIndexed { index, availability ->
            builder.addFormDataPart("availabilities[$index]", availability.toString())
        }

        return builder.build()
    }
}

